# to check type of input in c++

Tags: c++, typechecking

## To check type of data entered in cpp ##

```
int main()
{
    int num;
    stack<int> numberStack;
    while(1)
    {
        cin>>num;
        if(isdigit(num))
            numberStack.push(num);
        else
            break;
    }
return(0);
}
```

If I declare a variable as interger, and I input an alphabet, say 'B', instead of the number, can I check this behavior of user? My code above exits when first number is entered and does not wait for more inputs.

Comment: Please don't make fun of my question. I am trying to learn cpp

Comment: Start by reading the documentation of all the constructions that you use in your code.

Comment: First you do not check if reading the number succeeded. Use something like `if (!(cin >> num)){ cout << "Failed reading number"; break;}`. Secondly [`isdigit`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isdigit/) checks a character, but you read an `int` with `cin`. You probably want `num` to be a `char`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the [`std::isdigit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit) function checks if a *character* is a digit.

Secondly, by using the input operator `>>` you will make sure that the input is a number, or a [state flag](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/iostate) will be set in the `std::cin` object. Therefore do e.g.

```
while (std::cin >> num)
    numberStack.push(num);
```

The loop will then end if there's an error, end of file, or you input something that is not a valid `int`.

Answer (score 1):

First take your input as string

Using builtin libraries like isdigit() classify it as an integer

else if it contains '.'then its a float

else if it a alphanumerical the it is a string thats it

Code for this is below,

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;

int isint(char a[])
{
    int len=strlen(a);
    int minus=0;
    int dsum=0;
    for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
    {
        if(isdigit(a[i])!=0)
            dsum++;
        else if(a[i]=='-')
            minus++;        
    }
    if(dsum+minus==len)
        return 1;
    else 
        return 0;
}
int isfloat(char a[])
{
    int len=strlen(a);
    int dsum=0;
    int dot=0;
    int minus=0;
    for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
    {
        if(isdigit(a[i])!=0)
        {
            dsum++;
        }
        else if(a[i]=='.')
        {
            dot++;
        }
        else if(a[i]=='-')
        {
            minus++;
        }       
    }
    if(dsum+dot+minus==len)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
int main()
{
    char a[100];
    cin>>a; 
    
    if(isint(a)==1)
    {
        cout<<"This input is of type Integer";
    }
    else if(isfloat(a)==1)
    {
        cout<<"This input is of type Float";
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"This input is of type String";
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer

Comment: Don't dump code. Explain your solution, any pitfalls, and how it helps.

Comment: I like how this has obviously been adapted from Java code that one can find by Googling the string literals

Answer (score 0):

use cin.fail() to check error and clean the input buffer.

```
int num;
while (1) {
    cin >> num;
    if (cin.fail()) {
        cin.clear();
        cin.sync();
        cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        continue;
    }
    if (num == -1) {
        break;
    }
    numberStack.push(num);
}
```